# QGIS spatial join - join all features, not just one

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-join

I'm trying to do a spatial join of a feature on a polygon layer (p1) that intersects with two features of another polygon layer (p2)) via QGIS.

What I want: get the attributes of both features of p2 (name as string) into the attribute table of p1, not just the first one. Sum feature just works with int/double and no with strings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is pretty much the same as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120229/ The short version is you can't do this - you have a one to many relationship, and are trying to write two different values into the same attribute field. You have three choices - duplicate p1's shape once for each matching p2; use a relate instead of a join; write the p2 attributes into a single or multiple new fields in p1 - but note you then have the same attribute in multiple places, making use/analysis difficult.