# Joining polygons to points when the points fall in the intersection of polygons. QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, spatial-join

I am using QGIS. I am hoping to join a set of geocoded points to polygons in such a way that the new snapefile will be points that have a new field which lists the attributes of the polygon it lies in for each point.  I know this is a simple problem that can be taken care of by the join attributes by location function.

Where the problem comes in for me is that I have many points that lie in the intersection of up multiple polygons.  The outcome I'm looking for is a way to join the points and polygons in such a way that we have points that sequentially list the attributes of each of the multiple polygons it may lie in (with my data the points fall in at most 4 or 5 polygons at once).

Basically the polygons have unique names, I would like to perform some sort of join where I would receive for each point a list of the unique markers of the polygons they fall into.

Comment: Have you looked at  [spatial join of a single point to multiple polygons](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155264/spatial-join-of-a-single-point-to-multiple-polygons?rq=1) yet? Depending on the end result you wanted, it might work for you.

Comment: Hey, I did not see that page yet.  Looks promising. Thank you.